# Applying fade in effect while adding <li> elements to <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to apply fade-in (or just any effect) while adding new `<li>` elements to existing list.
Example:
Say this is my existing list

```
<ul class='ul-1'>
<li class='cl'></li>
<li class='cl'></li>
<li class='cl'></li>
</ul>
```

Now I need to prepend three more `<li>` elements to it
say:

```
<li class='cl'></li>
<li class='cl'></li>
<li class='cl'></li>
```

fetched via ajax and when these new `<li>`are prepended to list at that time I need to apply a fade in effect.Also I have to make sure that all new three element fade in simultaneously.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: A little bit of code will help :P

Comment: There are examples on the linked page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
$('#add').click(function(){
    $('<li />', {
        class: 'cl',
        html: idx++
    }).hide().appendTo('.ul-1').fadeIn()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nEcwN/)

Comment: That gave me right direction, here is example http://jsfiddle.net/4B5j4/7/ , have you realized that this made you God, because god never tells the answer he only shows you right direction.